# Returning undefined in output

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I am struggling to understand the return statement:

```js
function solution(number){
     var newarray = []
     for ( var i = 0 ; i < number - 1 ; i++ ) {
        if (i % 3 === 0) {
           newarray.push(number[i]);
        } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
           newarray.push(number[i]);
        } else {
           newarray
        }
      }
      return newarray
    }
    
   console.log(solution(10));
```

This solution is returning an array with values in but they are all undefined. Why is this the case? What essential concept am I missing can anyone help me?

Comment: `number[i]`? number seems to be a.. Number, not an array. That said, the last else is unnecessary (and syntactically incorrect). Also, the first two ifs can be condensed in `if (i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0)`. As long as they do the same (which seems to be the case), it's fine to have them condensed. Moreover, with number - 1 you're analizing from 0 to 8 in your case. Not sure whether that's intended.

Comment: should be `.push(i)`

Comment: I have been splitting strings for the past day, what an obvious miss! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to push only `i` to the `newArray`. `i` here is already a `Number`.

Also since `number` variable inside the function is a `primitive` and not an `object` or an `array`, therefore `number[i]` gives you `undefined` because it has no property corresponding to value of `i`.

Also, the last else is not required as it is doing nothing.

```
function solution(number){
 var newarray = []
 for ( var i = 0 ; i < number - 1 ; i++ ) {
    if (i % 3 === 0) {
       newarray.push(i);
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
       newarray.push(i);
    } 
  }
  return newarray
}

solution(10);//returns [0, 3, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

The number passed as input is 10.

You access the number in the for loop as number[i], so you are actually accessing the i-nth position of a number which is `undefined`.

change it to

```
newarray.push(i);
```

Comment: Can you please explain why -1 to the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function solution(number){
 var newarray = []
 for ( var i = 0 ; i < number - 1 ; i++ ) {
    if (i % 3 === 0) {
       newarray.push(i);
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
       newarray.push(i);
    } else {
       newarray
    }
  }
 return newarray;
} 

console.log(solution(10));
```